# Prestashop 1.4 - How to execute an initial MySQL query on every request

Tags: mysql, prestashop

Kind of old version of Prestashop, I know, but I need to execute an initial MySQL query **on every request**.

Where do I need to put the logic to be `always` executed?
Sort of initialization point the application always executes, no matter what URL is requested.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution (and smartly, I think).
And I also think this approach could be applicable to other versions of Prestashop (1.5, 1.6, 1.7...).

In `classes/MySQL.php` file, within the `connect` function, I add my query just before returning `$this->_link`:

```
public function connect()
{
    if (!defined('_PS_DEBUG_SQL_'))
        define('_PS_DEBUG_SQL_', false);
    if ($this->_link = mysql_connect($this->_server, $this->_user, $this->_password))
    {
        if (!$this->set_db($this->_database))
            die('The database selection cannot be made.');
    }
    else
        die('Link to database cannot be established.');
    /* UTF-8 support */
    if (!mysql_query('SET NAMES \'utf8\'', $this->_link))
        die(Tools::displayError('PrestaShop Fatal error: no utf-8 support. Please check your server configuration.'));
    // removed SET GLOBAL SQL_MODE : we can't do that (see PSCFI-1548)

    /** MY QUERY IS INSERTED HERE, USING $this->_link BY THE WAY **/
    mysql_query('...', $this->_link);

    return $this->_link;
}
```

In this way, 2 advantages arise:

1. I do not have to maintain a copy of database credentials other than Prestashop's
2. The query is executed in every request, both shop frontoffice and backoffice user interfaces.

I hope this can help anyone.